# Conjunctions with should

Tags: grammar

1. What are all of the subordinate conjunctions in the clauses of which 'should' can come? 
   (If I should~/so that I should~/lest I should~)
2. I think that 'should' used with subordinate conjunctions has the role of making a future tense or "assuming meaning", similar to 'will'?  I want to know about this, too.

Comment: Would you give us an example of what you're talking about? Homemade grammar descriptions are hard to deal with.

Comment: I've edited it.

Comment: Thank you. _Should_ is of course not the only modal auxiliary that can be used this way. _If I may, so that you could, lest he might_. And of course, _will_  is yet another modal.

Comment: Thank you. And could you answer my questions?

Comment: No, because there is no special list of subordinating conjunctions that go with _should_, or any other modal. The conjunctions and the modals are not particularly related, and there is no special construction involved. One could probly find examples with most [subordinate conjunctions](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/subordinatingconjunctions.pdf) and most modals.